# How to wait for asynchronous subtasks to complete in Celery

Tags: python, celery

Here are the tasks:

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery import Celery
import time

celery = Celery("example_tasks", backend="rpc://", broker="amqp://")


@shared_task
def parent_task():
    print("Starting parent task.")
    for i in range(2):
        result = child_task.delay(i)


@shared_task
def child_task(index):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"Starting child task {index}.")
```

Here is the main program:

```
from celery import Celery
import time
from example_tasks import parent_task

app = Celery("tasks", backend="rpc://", broker="amqp://")

result = parent_task.delay()
```

At the end of the main program, what is the best way to wait until all tasks (subtasks included) have finished?

Comment: Wrap them in a Chord.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use `list(result.collect())`.

```
collect(intermediate=False, **kwargs)

Collect results as they return.

Iterator, like get() will wait for the task to complete, but will also follow AsyncResult and ResultSet returned by the task, yielding (result, value) tuples for each result in the tree.
```

see [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html?highlight=AsyncResult#celery.result.AsyncResult.collect) for more details.

### Explaination

The `AsyncResult.collect()` method is described in page [Canvas: Designing Work-flows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) and looks like that this method only works for workflows, you need some primitives to build a result graph, but actually Celery will automaticly find the task parent when task was created(by [self.current_worker_task](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/base.py#L719-L730)).

That is to say, when you create a subtask, you build a result graph and `AsyncResult.collect()` is for you.